# Как на OpenServer настроить отдачу изображений через Nginx, а скриптов через Apache?

Tags: nginx, apache, openserver

Использую OpenServer. Apache 2.4 в связке с Nginx 1.17. Есть может где руководство пошаговое, как распределить нагрузку, чтобы скрипты исполнялись Apache'ем, а неисполняемые файлы отдавались Nginx?

Comment: Поставьте nginx перед апачем и отдавайте апачу только те запросы, которые подразумевают выполнение скриптов. Разделяйте с помощью location, например, /images/ и /static/ отрабатывайте непосредственно nginx'ом, а всё остальное отдавайте апачу через proxy_pass, пусть он разбирается. Или наоборот, какие-нибудь /scripts/ или \.php отдавайте апачу через proxy_pass, а всё остальное отрабатывайте как статику.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, да, спасибо за ответ. Я понял в какую сторону нужно копать.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не воспользоваться `php-fpm (FastCGI)` в связке с `nginx`?

> неисполняемые файлы

Вы подразумеваете статические файлы, которые могут кешироваться?
Да `nginx` умеет это делать, предварительно настроив правильно конфиг сайта, согласно документации на сайте [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/#processes).

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться php-fpm (FastCGI) в связке с nginx?


Потому что это Windows.

Comment: @Мурчик , прощу прощения, вы хотите сказать что — это не реализуемо на Windows? php-fpm + nginx ставится легко даже на Windows [пример готового LAMP сервера](https://winginx.com)